# Vee-validate: "No such validator 'required_if' exists."

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

I'm using `vee-validate` v3 with Vue 2.7. Specifically, here's the `vee-validate` entry in my `package.json`:

```
"vee-validate": "^3.4.5",
```

I'm having trouble getting the `required_if` rule working. When I try to use it, I get the error

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: No such validator 'required_if' exists.
```

Here is the code:

```
<ValidationObserver>
  <ValidationProvider rules="" vid="country" v-slot="x">
    <select v-model="country">
      <option value="US">United States</option>
      <option value="OTHER">Other country</option>
    </select>
  </ValidationProvider>

  <ValidationProvider rules="required_if:country,US" v-slot="{ errors }">
    <input type="text" placeholder="state" v-model="state" />
    <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
  </ValidationProvider>
</ValidationObserver>
```

You may notice that this is in fact basically the exact example they give in their own documentation for the `required_if` rule over on https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3/guide/rules.html. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here to get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import these rules, they are not installed by default

you can add these lines in you component:

```
import { required_if } from "vee-validate/dist/rules";
import { extend } from "vee-validate";
extend("required_if", required_if);
```

or you can create a plugin file and add all the rules that are not nstalled by default

```
import { extend } from 'vee-validate';
import * as rules from 'vee-validate/dist/rules';

Object.keys(rules).forEach(rule => {
 extend(rule, rules[rule]);
});

for (let [rule, validation] of Object.entries(rules)) {
 extend(rule, {
  ...validation
 });
}
```

ref: https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3/guide/rules.html

*ps: make sure you have vee-validate greater than v3.1*

Comment: I find this weird because the documentation says that this rule already comes with the library. I do have other custom rules that I added using `extend()` and those work as expected, but the documentation I linked says that `required_if` is a predefined rule that comes with `vee-validate` by default. When using any of the other rules shown in the docs, they just work out of the box with no need to "redefine" them. I've essentially solved this by defining a custom rule that acts like I would expect `required_if` to act. I don't think the docs are clear enough in this regard.

Comment: Its clear under the [#Installing All Rules](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3/guide/rules.html#installing-all-rules) section!